# CSS or jQuery: How to add a fade effect to an element got with getElementById?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, getelementbyid, fade

I think this is a pretty simple question.

I have a script which replace a text on my website. I would love to add a fade-effect while replacing. What should I do?

```js
var target = document.getElementById('target');
var titles = [
  'Text1',
  'Text2',
  'Text3'
];

function newTitle () {
    var i = (Math.random() * titles.length) | 0;
    target.innerText = titles[i];
}

newTitle();
```

```html
 <p id="target"></p>
<button onclick="newTitle()">Replace</div>
```

Comment: What kind of fade effect?  Do you want to use css or jquery?

Comment: doesn't matter :)

Comment: there will be a easy solution and a more complex solution. i will choose the easy solution. doesn't matter if jquery or css. if you have a jquery-solution, i will take it. if you have a css-solution, i will take it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example. I utilized `setInterval` and change the text's `opacity` over time - just vanilla JavaScript

```js
var target = document.getElementById('target');
var titles = [
  'Text1',
  'Text2',
  'Text3'
];


function newTitle() {  
document.getElementById("trigger").disabled = true;
var i = (Math.random() * titles.length) | 0;
  var width = 0;
  var opacity = 0;
  target.style.opacity = opacity; 
  target.innerText = titles[i];
  var c = setInterval(fade, 100);
  function fade() {
    if (opacity>1) {
      clearInterval(c);
document.getElementById("trigger").disabled = false;
      return;
    } else {
      opacity += 0.1;
      target.style.opacity = opacity; 
    }
  }
  
}
```

```html
<p id="target">Text1</p>
            <button id="trigger" onclick="newTitle()">Replace</div>
```

Comment: this is a little bit strange. it fades for example text1 out and in an then replace it without a fade. you see?

Answer (score 2):

1. Add a CSS effect to `transition`, specific for `opacity`.
2. In your function, change the element opacity to 0.
3. Add a timeout before changing the text (use the same time you added in the transition effect).
4. When timer ends, change the text and opacity back to 1.

See below code:

```js
var target = document.getElementById('target');
var titles = [
  'Text1',
  'Text2',
  'Text3'
];

function newTitle () {
    var i = (Math.random() * titles.length) | 0;
    target.style.opacity = "0";
    setTimeout(function(){
      target.innerText = titles[i];
      target.style.opacity = "1";
    }, 600);
}


newTitle();
```

```css
#target{
  transition: opacity .6s ease;
}
```

```html
<p id="target"></p>
<button onclick="newTitle()">Replace</div>
```